# Finding max value of an attribute of objects in a dictionary

Tags: python, object, dictionary

I have a collection of objects stored in a dictionary, and I am wanting to retrieve the maximum value of a particular attribute. The objects are cookies (think chocolate chip), and each cookie has its own temperature, heat capacity, batch number, etc. The batch number describes which set of cookies it exited the oven with.

```
class Cookie:
def __init__(self, density, specificheat, batch):
    self.rho = density
    self.cp = specificheat
    self.batch = batch
    self.volume = 1.2e-5        # m^3
    self.surfarea = 4.9e-3      # m^2
    ...
```

I want to find the maximum batch number in the dictionary. I know this would be simple if I were using a list, I could just use operator.attrgetter('batch') to sort the list and get the value. However, using a dictionary, this line does not work:

```
sorted(cookies, key=operator.attrgetter('batch'))
```

I could set up a for loop and go through every single object in the dictionary, but I feel there is a better way to do this. I want to avoid switching to a list because I'm running an optimization sorting the cookies into boxes, and it is faster to retrieve data from a dictionary than from a list when you have to worry about 2000 cookies. (I timed it using timeit()). I've looked for similar questions on Stackoverflow, but most of them seem to be in javascript. The Python questions I've found are for dictionaries that don't store objects like mine. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use max on the values:

```
mx_batch =  max(cookies.values(), key=operator.attrgetter('batch')).batch
```

Or just use a class attribute to keep the max:

```
class Cookie:
    mx  = 0
    def __init__(self, density, specificheat, batch):
        self.rho = density
        self.cp = specificheat
        self.batch = batch
        self.volume = 1.2e-5        # m^3
        self.surfarea = 4.9e-3      # m^2
        if batch > Cookie.mx:
            Cookie.mx = batch
```

Then:

```
In [9]: c1 = Cookie(1, 120, 1)

In [10]: c2 = Cookie(2, 120, 4)

In [11]: c3 = Cookie(1, 120, 2)

In [12]: c4 = Cookie(1, 120, 1)

In [13]: print(Cookie.mx)
4
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me:
    cookie_maxbatch = max(cookies.values(), key=operator.attrgetter('batch'))
    nbatches = cookie_maxbatch.getbatch()

Comment: To state the obvious, the latter technique is not suitable if cookies are ever removed or updated

Comment: @FujiApple, the cookie could be updated once the batch was not changed which seems unlikely as a batch is not something that should really change, if objects are deleted then obviously all bets are off unless the OP is actually keeping a Counter of batches.

Comment: @magnoliafork, are you sure batch itself should not be a class attribute? How/where does the batch get created?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham each batch is a set of cookies that all get baked in the oven at the same time, so the batch number is predetermined at the beginning of the calculation. My assumption is that the oven can hold 100 cookies at a time, so I assign each randomly generated cookie a batch number depending on where it is in the line of cookies: (batch = j // 100 + 1) where j belongs to (0, 999). It is correct that the set of cookies and the batches they belong to will not change, they are the static portion of my optimization, which focuses on the best way to put them in boxes.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I didn't even realize I could do your second suggestion! (new to Python) That's a great idea for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it

```
# where objs is your dictionary of cookies
max(map(lambda i: objs[i].batch, objs))
```